# How do I get rid of the error line marker in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I get an error or warning after attempting to run my code, I usually double click the error message to jump directly to the problem. However, it leaves a line marker on the scrollbar which prevents me from scrolling away, even after I fix it:
[image: Scroll Bar]

Is there any way to clear that marker so I can scroll freely again?

Comment: Just pointing out, the blue marker is for caret position.

Answer (score 1):

Customize the scroll bar by going to:
**Tools** - **Options** - **Text Editor** - **All Languages** - **Scroll Bars**
and uncheck the appropriate item:
[image: Scroll bar]